# Sync music to ipod 4g

Tags: music, ipod

I want to sync music to ipod 4g device, without the use of itunes in ubuntu 10.04, I used to do this with gtkpod until gtkpod stopped supporting fourth generation ipods.

I tried to setup itunes with wine, but in vain. Is there any other open source software which can help me with this ? I do not want to instal windows for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use banshee to sync my 1st gen iPod touch. It works fine most of the times.

Comment: I tried banshee as well, it seems gtkpod and banshee have stopped supporting 4th gen ipods.